# requirejs setup work

Tags: javascript, jquery, requirejs

I'm finding it difficult to use the info on require.js site in my own projects.

One question I have is based on the sample code on the require.js site:

> define(function () {
>
> ```
> //Do setup work here
>
> return {
>     color: "black",
>     size: "unisize"
> }
> ```
>
> });

Can someone please give me an example what could goes in the `Do setup work here` section?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your own code. If you only want to return a plain object, there's nothing else to add.